# FloatingActionButton appears to be a square on lollipop instead of circular on the android studio preview

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I'm a newbie to material theme. I'm using android studio and I've been trying to add a floating action button but unfortunately it appears to be a square on the preview on lollipop on my work PC. This is really strange because on my macbook at home the preview shows up as a circular floating action button.

I have added the support library lines on to the gradle as well but I still have no luck. I downloaded the famous cheesesquare example from the github with all the support library demos and it seems to work fine.

also another issue is that the autocompletion seems to fail inside the xml tags on floating action button

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this if it helps stackoverflow.com/questions/30538604/fab-square-on-pre-lollipop-and-without-shadow-on-lollipop. Also its fixed in the new update. see if you have the updated design support library

Comment: I actually got the new update 1.3 on the stable channel but no luck and I tried switching to the canary channel and updated to 1.3.1 to see if there is any fix on it but unfortunately no luck.

Comment: not the android studio check your version of design support library.

Comment: yeah I got 22.2.1 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design support library update fixed it!